# ndnSIM2.0 appear error when I use "./waf"

Tags: c++, linux, waf, ndnsim

reference to:http://ndnsim.net/2.0/getting-started.html#compiling-and-running-ndnsim

My step are as follow:

```
cd ndnSIM/ndn-cxx
./waf configure --boost-includes=/home/li/ndnSIM/boost_1_58_0 --boost-libs=/home/li/ndnSIM/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib
./waf
```

But it can't success when I use ".waf".It will appear red error,such as:

```
Build failed
-> task in '../bin/tlvdump' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140364876652240: cxxprogram tlvdump.cpp.3.o -> tlvdump}
['/usr/bin/g++', 'tools/tlvdump.cpp.3.o', '-o', '/home/li/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build/bin/tlvdump', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-L.', '-lndn-cxx', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-L/home/li/ndnSIM/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib', '-L/usr/lib', '-lboost_system', '-lboost_filesystem', '-lboost_date_time', '-lboost_iostreams', '-lboost_regex', '-lboost_program_options', '-lboost_chrono', '-lboost_random', '-lcryptopp', '-lsqlite3', '-lrt', '-lpthread']
-> task in '../bin/ndncatchunks3' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140364876581200: cxxprogram ndncatchunks3.cpp.1.o -> ndncatchunks3}
['/usr/bin/g++', 'tools/ndncatchunks3.cpp.1.o', '-o', '/home/li/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build/bin/ndncatchunks3', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-L.', '-lndn-cxx', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-L/home/li/ndnSIM/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib', '-L/usr/lib', '-lboost_system', '-lboost_filesystem', '-lboost_date_time', '-lboost_iostreams', '-lboost_regex', '-lboost_program_options', '-lboost_chrono', '-lboost_random', '-lcryptopp', '-lsqlite3', '-lrt', '-lpthread']
```

My os is Ubuntu14.04(64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, There are no man answers my question, Maybe it due to a simple reason, Because my gcc's version is 5.1.0, ndnSIM2.0 just need to previous version, such as 4.8.2,and recompile boost,It will be success.